# How to crop a user defined shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I have created a right arrow with Pen Tool, [image].

The layer is [image]

Now I want to crop the right arrow only. I have tried slice tool but I get

[image]

which have a white background.

But what I want is only the grey right arrow.

How could I get it?

Thanks.

Comment: you can do it manually as it written below, or if you will be doing it a lot of time, this plugin save you much time http://getenigma64.com/

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate the layer in question,
Right click it (in the layers tab) and click rasterize layer.
[image]

Now you have it singled out, without  a mask or background.
You can put it in its own document and save it as a PNG or GIF, saving transparency.

**Edit:**
In reply to your comment,
A quick way to export with *multiple* (or even single) layers, is to do the following:
It only exports layers that are visible, unless you specify otherwise.
[image]

There is also another method:

Create a new document, then click and drag the layer you want isolated to the new document, crop around it and make you you've disabled your background layer, then save as GIF or PNG.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried to save the arrow with transparency background but I failed(I followed this tut http://www.myjanee.com/tuts/save/savexgifs.htm).Why?

Comment: @Jichao - I edited my post, and the tutorial you posted should work.

Comment: @Jichao - A thought just occured to me, make sure that your `background` layer is TURNED OFF, else it will save with your other layers.

Answer (score 3):

To merely just crop the custom shape:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>click</kbd> the shape's `Vector mask thumbnail` in the `Layers` window to choose all the shape's pixels. Then select `Image` → `Crop` to crop to selection.

However, slicing should work fine. Just make sure all layers (including the `Background` layer, as @Johannes commented) behind the shape layer are `OFF`. If you need the background layer, do the `Save for Web & Devices…` step in two runs: one with the background and one without; you could always choose which slices you want to save per saving.